# How can I suppress ending newline in write()?

Tags: r

When doing

```
write("Hello", file = "Test.txt")
```

and open up my file `Test.txt` in a text editor, it contains two rows (where the second is empty). How can I suppress `write()` from inserting the ending newline command?

Comment: The documentation of `write()` says that `write()` is a wrapper for  `cat()`. `cat("Hello", file="test.txt")` does not insert a new line. Maybe you can just use cat()? this does not answer you question of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write` is a wrapper for `cat`. If we use `cat` like this, we got same result:

```
cat("Hello",file="Test.txt",sep="\n")
```

If we use cat without sep argument, we have text without new line:

```
cat("Hello",file="Test.txt")
```

Another way for writing is using `cat` + `sink`:

```
sink("Test.txt")
cat("Hello")
sink()
```

For suppress `write()` I don't find way.

Comment: Even *with* `sep` argument, `cat` won’t print a newline.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I testing and I got new line.

Comment: Use a `sep` different from `'\n'`: e.g. `' '`, as `write` does. In fact, `cat` is terribly inconsistent in its treatment of parameters — a true nightmare. I’d suggest using it as little as possible (`message` is often more appropriate) and, when using it, to pass a *single* character vector to it that already contains the formatted object. Relying on `cat` to do anything more than dumbly outputting a single string is prone to yield funny results.